# Jqgrid with struts2

Tags: struts2, jqgrid

I have list of objects and I need to show it in JSP. Th ajax call action that I am sending to struts.xml is

**STRUTS.XML**

```
<action name="getjsondata"  class="com.sample.Getjson">      
   <result type="json"/>        
</action>
```

**Getjson.java**

```
List<Employee> employeeList;
//Getter and Setter

public String execute(){
   employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
   Employee employee = new Employee();
   employee.setId(1);
   employee.setName("Name 1");
   employee.setLastName("Last Name 1");

   employee2 = new Employee();
   employee2.setId(1);
   employee2.setName("Name 1");
   employee2.setLastName("Last Name 1");

   employeeList.add(employee);
   employeeList.add(employee2);

  return SUCCESS;
}
```

**MyJSP.jsp**

```
                $("#list").jqGrid({
                    url: "getjsondata.action",
                    datatype: "json",
                    mtype: "GET",
                    multiselect :  true,
                    colNames: ["Id", "Name" , "Last Name"],
                    colModel: [
                        {name: "id", width: 80},
                        {name: "name", width: 150},
                        {name: "lastname", width: 150}
                    ],
                    pager: "#pager",
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    sortname: "id",
                    sortorder: "desc",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    autoencode: true,
                    caption: "Employee List"
                });
```

The jqgrid is never populated. Can any one suggest what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22961753/573032

Comment: Also, why not using struts2-jquery-grid-plugin instead of raw jqgrid ?

Comment: Is `execute` method being called? Any errors in console?

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks for comments. The execute method is called and the list is getting populated also. But I am not clear about how to display in it jqgrid.